# Reading parameter values from testng suite file in guice

Tags: testng, integration-testing, integration, guice

I am trying to integrate testng + guice module for integration test. Guice modules need an argument based on each stage: (Let's say credential  key). I was looking for what is the best way to pass that value to guice module. 
Is there a way I can use @Parameter defined in suite file inside guice module?

Answer (score 1):

Guice module constructors with `ITestContext` param are supposed to work.

From [`ITestContext`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestContext.html), you'll be able to find everything you need.